# Nginx Plus vod , forbidden but static files fine

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to serve a video file from a fresh nginx plus install on centos 7. I added the conf

```
server {
 listen 80;
 root /usr/share/nginx/html;
 location /video
{}
}
```

The conf file is running on user nginx by default.

When I try to access http://192.168.1.172/video/t.mp4, I get a forbidden 403, the error log as permission denied.

I have set owner/chmod to user nginx. The other static files in the same folder, t.html is served fine.

```
[root@localhost video]# ls -al
total 1820480
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root  root          31 Nov  6  2017 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root  root        4096 Nov  6  2017 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  root           9 Nov  6  2017 t.html
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 nginx nginx 1864160493 Feb 14  2017 t.mp4
```

The error log

```
2017/11/06 06:54:04 [error] 2118#2118: *9 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/video/t.mp4" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.1.99, server: localhost, request: "GET /video/t.mp4 HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.172"
```

Answer (score 0):

it is selinux mode, need to disable it

Comment: It would be helpful if you could expand on your answer.